# How to append all the loop elements in single line while using string Template?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, append, stringtemplate

I have tried to make a Template for example.py by using string Template where I substitute each for loop elements in $i ["CA:"+**$i**+':'+" "]. Partially it works but substituting only the last element.

But, I want to append all the values in single line with certain format .

**For example:**

**What my current script doing is follows:**

```
for i in range(1,4):
    #It takes each "i" elements and substituting only the last element
    str='''s=selection( self.atoms["CA:"+$i+':'+" "].select_sphere(10) )
```

**What I am getting is as follows:**

```
    s=selection( self.atoms["CA:"+3+':'+" "].select_sphere(10) )
```

**What, I am expecting is as follows:**

```
    s=selection ( self.atoms["CA:"+1+':'+" "].select_sphere(10),self.atoms["CA:"+2+':'+" "].select_sphere(10),self.atoms["CA:"+3+':'+" "].select_sphere(10) )
```

**My script:**

```
import os
from string import Template
for i in range(1,4):

    str='''
    s=selection( self.atoms["CA:"+$i+':'+" "].select_sphere(10) )
    '''
    str=Template(str)
    file = open(os.getcwd() + '/' + 'example.py', 'w')
    file.write(str.substitute(i=i))
    file.close()
```

I use this two scripts to get my desired output:

```
import os
from string import Template
a=[]
for i in range(1,4):
     a.append(''.join("self.atoms["+ "'CA:' "+str(i)+""':'+" "+"]"+".select_sphere(10)"))

str='''s=selection( $a ).by_residue()'''
str=Template(str)
file = open(os.getcwd() + '/' + 'example.py', 'w')
file.write(str.substitute(a=a))

with open('example.py', 'w') as outfile:
     selection_template = '''self.atoms["CA:"+{}+':'+" "].select_sphere(10)'''
     selections = [selection_template.format(i) for i in range(1, 4)]
     outfile.write('s = selection({})\n'.format(', '.join(selections)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that your code, because it opens the output file with mode `'w'`, overwrites the file on each iteration of the for loop. That is why you only see the last one in the file.

Also I wouldn't use `string.Template` to perform these substitutions. Just use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.format#str.format). Generate a list of selections and use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.format#str.join) to produce the final string:

```
with open('example.py', 'w') as outfile:
    selection_template = 'self.atoms["CA:"+{}+":"+" "].select_sphere(10)'
    selections = [selection_template.format(i) for i in range(1, 4)]
    outfile.write('s = selection({})\n'.format(', '.join(selections)))
```

Here `selection_template` uses `{}` as a placeholder for variable substitution and a list comprehension is used to construct the selection strings. These selection strings are then joined together using the string `', '` as the separator and the resulting string inserted into the call to `selection()`, again using `str.format()`.

Comment: Thanks alot mhawke

Answer (score 1):

In this example I use Python's built-in `format` string method, which is relatively easy to understand. If you prefer to use string templating you can easily adapt it.

The trick is to observe that there are two separate operations to perform:

1. Create the list of arguments
2. Substitute the argument list in the required output line

I use a generator-expression argument to `join` to achieve the necessary iteration and part 1, and then a simple string formatting to accomplish step 2.

I use the string's `format` method as a bound function to simplify the code by abbreviating the method calls.

```
main_format = '''
s = selection({})
'''.format
item_format = 'self.atoms["CA:"+{s}+\':\'+" "].select_sphere(10)'.format
items = ", ".join(item_format(s=i) for i in range(1, 4))
print(main_format(items))
```